# Unable to upload csv data on the elastic search server

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, kibana, elastic-stack, elk

I am trying to upload the contents of the `*.csv` file onto the `Elasticsearch server` and while executing the config file the following logs are recorded:

```
Sending Logstash logs to C:/ELK/logstash-7.0.0/logs which is now configured via log4j2.properties
[2023-07-03T12:55:40,333][WARN ][logstash.config.source.multilocal] Ignoring the 'pipelines.yml' file because modules or command line options are specified
[2023-07-03T12:55:40,354][INFO ][logstash.runner          ] Starting Logstash {"logstash.version"=>"7.0.0"}
[2023-07-03T12:55:44,039][INFO ][logstash.outputs.elasticsearch] Elasticsearch pool URLs updated {:changes=>{:removed=>[], :added=>[http://10.0.51.128:16000/]}}
[2023-07-03T12:55:44,284][WARN ][logstash.outputs.elasticsearch] Restored connection to ES instance {:url=>"http://10.0.51.128:16000/"}
[2023-07-03T12:55:44,351][INFO ][logstash.outputs.elasticsearch] ES Output version determined {:es_version=>7}
[2023-07-03T12:55:44,355][WARN ][logstash.outputs.elasticsearch] Detected a 6.x and above cluster: the `type` event field won't be used to determine the document _type {:es_version=>7}
[2023-07-03T12:55:44,383][INFO ][logstash.outputs.elasticsearch] New Elasticsearch output {:class=>"LogStash::Outputs::ElasticSearch", :hosts=>["//10.0.51.128:16000"]}
[2023-07-03T12:55:44,399][INFO ][logstash.outputs.elasticsearch] Using mapping template from {:path=>"C:\\Users\\kunal.rathi\\Downloads\\jacoco-client\\jacoco-client\\data\\AXIA\\report\\2023-06-28\\b320181e3e06beac9b020c8a430bb934\\mapping.json"}
[2023-07-03T12:55:44,424][INFO ][logstash.javapipeline    ] Starting pipeline {:pipeline_id=>"main", "pipeline.workers"=>8, "pipeline.batch.size"=>125, "pipeline.batch.delay"=>50, "pipeline.max_inflight"=>1000, :thread=>"#<Thread:0x8968804 run>"}
[2023-07-03T12:55:44,567][INFO ][logstash.outputs.elasticsearch] Attempting to install template {:manage_template=>{"index_patterns"=>"logstash-*", "settings"=>{"number_of_shards"=>1, "index.lifecycle.name"=>"logstash-policy", "index.lifecycle.rollover_alias"=>"logstash"}, "mappings"=>{"properties"=>{"GROUP"=>{"type"=>"keyword"}, "PACKAGE"=>{"type"=>"keyword"}, "CLASS"=>{"type"=>"keyword"}, "INSTRUCTION_MISSED"=>{"type"=>"integer"}, "INSTRUCTION_COVERED"=>{"type"=>"integer"}, "BRANCH_MISSED"=>{"type"=>"integer"}, "BRANCH_COVERED"=>{"type"=>"integer"}, "LINE_MISSED"=>{"type"=>"integer"}, "LINE_COVERED"=>{"type"=>"integer"}, "COMPLEXITY_MISSED"=>{"type"=>"integer"}, "COMPLEXITY_COVERED"=>{"type"=>"integer"}, "METHOD_MISSED"=>{"type"=>"integer"}, "METHOD_COVERED"=>{"type"=>"integer"}}}}}
[2023-07-03T12:55:44,604][INFO ][logstash.outputs.elasticsearch] Installing elasticsearch template to _template/jacoco_report_template
[2023-07-03T12:55:45,238][INFO ][logstash.javapipeline    ] Pipeline started {"pipeline.id"=>"main"}
[2023-07-03T12:55:45,298][INFO ][filewatch.observingtail  ] START, creating Discoverer, Watch with file and sincedb collections
[2023-07-03T12:55:45,304][INFO ][logstash.agent           ] Pipelines running {:count=>1, :running_pipelines=>[:main], :non_running_pipelines=>[]}
[2023-07-03T12:55:45,699][INFO ][logstash.agent           ] Successfully started Logstash API endpoint {:port=>9600}
```

The pipeline is getting created but the data is not being uploaded. I have set the `sincedb path` in the config file as "null".